# Separating values entered into a string

Tags: powershell, parameters, parameter-passing

So I am trying to create a Powershell menu that when the user selects a choice, it will ask for the value or values its trying to search (ex. Ping Multiple Computers). I am currently having a hard time getting that to work. I will post pictures to show what I mean

When I type in one name to search the command executes fine shown below:

[image: Working with One value entered]

When I try with multiple values it doesn't work:

[image: Not working with multiple values]

Here is a snap of the code I have:

[image: Sample of Code]

Any help of course is much appreciated.

****UPDATE** - 11/13**

**This is what I currently have:**

```
function gadc {
   Param(
       [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
       [string[]] $cname # Note: [string[]] (array), not [string]
       )
   $cname = "mw$cname"
   Get-ADComputer $cname
```

}

**This is the output in the Console**

```
cmdlet gadc at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
cname[0]: imanuel
cname[1]: troyw
cname[2]: hassan
cname[3]: 
Get-ADComputer : Cannot convert 'System.String[]' to the type 
'Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADComputer' required by parameter 'Identity'. Specified 
method is not supported.
At line:32 char:19
+    Get-ADComputer $cname
+                   ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADComputer], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.G 
   etADComputer
 
Press Enter to continue...: 

**And here is the other way with the same result:**

cmdlet gadc at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
cname[0]: imanuel, troyw

Get-ADComputer : Cannot convert 'System.String[]' to the type 
'Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADComputer' required by parameter 'Identity'. Specified 
method is not supported.
At line:32 char:19
+    Get-ADComputer $cname
+                   ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADComputer], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.G 
   etADComputer
```

Press Enter to continue...:

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please post your code, not _screenshots of your code_ :)

Comment: to reiterate the previous "post the text" msg [*grin*] ... Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question? - Meta Stack Overflow — https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: I did, in the second screen shot it doesn't show any output when I execute the command.

Comment: @Lee's wording was a bit ambiguous: what he meant to say is that you _shouldn't_ use images in general, only _text_; images, if required at all, should only ever _complement_ the textual information.

Comment: @agardi - as others have pointed out ... the "image of text" comments are about NOT posting images of text unless there is no other way to do the job. my link shows the _why_ behind that idea. [*grin*]

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare your mandatory parameter as an *array*, then PowerShell's automatic prompting will allow you to enter *multiple* values, *one by one* - simply press <kbd>Enter</kbd> by itself after having submitted the last value in order to continue:

```
function gadc {
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string[]] $cname  # Note: [string[]] (array), not [string]
  )
  # Get-ADComputer only accepts one computer name at a time 
  # (via the positionally implied -Identity parameter), so you must loop
  # over the names.
  # The following should work too, but is slightly slower:
  #   $cname | Get-ADComputer 
  foreach ($c in $cname) { Get-ADComputer $c }
}
```

Comment: @agardi - please see my update - you must loop over the elements of the name array. Also, since my answer is based on the _original_ form of your question - which exhibited the problem of _not using an array_, I suggest you edit your question to show the _original_ code, so that the question and the answer match.